# How can I hide the TabNavigator gap in Flex 4.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

[image]

I tried extending TabNavigator and overriding contentY, but it references **private tabBarHeight**, so to get around that I simply copied the getter contents into my override and subtracted the unwanted 12 pixels, but that made absolutely zero difference.

Anyone have any ideas (Aside from switching to a viewstack!)?

```
public class Tabber extends TabNavigator
{
    public function Tabber(){
        super();
    }

    override protected function get contentY():Number {
        var paddingTop:Number = getStyle("paddingTop");
        if (isNaN(paddingTop))
            paddingTop = 0;

        var tabHeight:Number = getStyle("tabHeight");
        if (isNaN(tabHeight))
            tabHeight = tabBar.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight();

        var tabBarHeight:Number = tabHeight - borderMetrics.top;
        return tabBarHeight + paddingTop - 12;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `tabHeight` (with `setStyle` method)?

Because [TabNavigator](https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/master/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/containers/TabNavigator.as) uses it:

```
private function get tabBarHeight():Number
{
    var tabHeight:Number = getStyle("tabHeight");

    if (isNaN(tabHeight))
        tabHeight = tabBar.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight();

    return tabHeight - borderMetrics.top;
}
```

Or maybe changing the `verticalGap` style...